# Create a font, with a file, whose path is an URL

Tags: java, file, fonts, custom-font

All is in the question :

How could i create a font with a path for the file of the font which is an URL ?
Because for the images, i made :

```
URL fond_path_3 = getClass().getResource("/hepta/Images/BoutonQuitter.png");
Image myPicture3 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(fond_path_3);
```

But now for a file i don't know how to get it :

```
URL font_path = getClass().getResource("/hepta/Images/moolbor.ttf");
newfont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream(new File(font_path))).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
```

The problem seems to be from :

```
new FileInputStream(new File(font_path))
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a FileInputStream, you should open a stream on the URL.

```
newfont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, font_path.openStream()).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
```

See also [InputStream from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932369/inputstream-from-a-file-url)