# Get response after HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String url) method

Tags: java, servlets

After HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String url) method calling I'm getting some response. How can I get this respose? sendRedirect returns void.

Comment: This is a strange question. Aren't you basically trying to ask something like as already answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932369/inputstream-from-a-url/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String url) responds to the browser instructing it to access the specified URL.

Comment: But if I need information, which displayed on redirected page, what i have to do?

Comment: This information is sent to the browser, not to server. It is unreachable for you (server side). If you need information, you have to make the browser send it to you.