# Parsing mp4 to raw audio file without download in JAVA

Tags: java, audio, flac, audio-converter

I need to parse mp4 file (which I get from URL), to raw audio file (FLAC) using JAVA, and I want to do that without actually download the file to my server.

I checked **sannies/mp4parser** library but the file need to be downloaded.
Is there any way to parse the mp4 to flac without download it?

Thanks

Comment: define *download* because you need to download *something*

Comment: by saying "download" i mean to save the file in my server.

Comment: then maybe try this answer to get an [InputStream from an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932369/inputstream-from-a-url)

Comment: Thanks but I know how to get InputStream from an url, but in order to convert it using the library I've mentioned - you need the file channel (from FileInputStream).

Comment: You could create your own FileInputStream implementation. Which not directly accesses the FileSystem but rather writes the data to an OutputStream