# Scanner Class And String Buffer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Whenever I use Scanner class for input it shows a warning regarding memory leak, ".in" not closed. While using Buffered Reader it does not show any warning. Why So?

```
    class Demo    
    {    
        public static void main(String[] arg){    
        System.out.println("Enter a String");    
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
        String[] str = new String[1];    
        str[0] = sc.next();    
        System.out.println(str[0]);    
    }
```

Comment: Can you show thw code please?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463327/is-this-a-memory-leak-or-a-false-positive) will help?

Comment: How does `String Buffer` relate to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either case, you should close the `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` to avoid resource leaks. The compiler apparently doesn't recognize the problem with `BufferedReader` and doesn't issue the warning.

Comment: Can you please explain how memory leaks? What if we define a string type array with only 1 value str[0] and taking only one input?

Comment: @user3436422, Add some code to your question so we can understand clearly.

Comment: @user3436422 The memory leak has nothing to do with the variables where you store the input. It is the `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` object itself that causes the leak. When you close the `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`, you release the operating system resources which are used by these classes.