# Java Scanner "unassigned closeable value" is never closed [Eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

Whenever I type the scanner as a "nested line" it will warn me that [Resource leak: 'unassigned closeable value' is never closed] and advised me to add `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` at top of it.

Is it right to just add the `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` as it advised or there is another way which is more preferable?

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String name = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();    
    System.out.printf("My name is %s", name);
}
```

Comment: Store the scanner in a variable, and then use `scanner.close()` at the end to close it

Comment: What is telling your this? The java compiler (what version?) or an IDE? When I run your code on the command line in Java 9, I am getting no such warning.

Comment: It seems a bit superfluous to complain about resources not getting freed on termination in any case.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11463327/5468463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE is likely warning you about not calling `close()`, because `Scanner` implements `Closable`. As you don't want to close `System.in`, suppress the warning, and forget about it. You can check your IDE's settings for what it should warn about (`resource`). It is simply just not detecting that the scanner is using `System.in`.

IntelliJ IDEA? You have probably enabled one or more of these:

`Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> Resource management -> ...`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use try-with-resource construct as below:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("My name is %s", name);
    }
```

Scanner is a resource and it needs to be closed. Either close it manually by calling close() method in finally block or use try-with-resource as above so that it closes the resource automatically.

Comment: Be careful: closing the Scanner will also close System.in, and you will not be able to do another `new Scanner(System.in)` in your application after you close it.