# How to curl an URL and saving output to a file using java

Tags: java, linux, curl

I'm a newbie in java and need help in how to use the `cURL` in java and saving the output of the `cURL` command to a file in runtime.

Let's consider as i'm using the below URL which i have to `cURL` in the linux machine.

`http://maniv.com/maniv/rest?method=sendMessage&msg_type=binary&parameter1=9999999&parameter2=9999999`

When i'm hitting the above URL using `curl "http://maniv.com/maniv/rest?method=sendMessage&msg_type=binary&parameter1=9999999&parameter2=9999999"` in linux, it will give the ouput as:

```
Message | sent | successfully
```

Now i need to write the output into a new file based on the `parameter1` as file name each time, when i change the `parameter1` and hit the URL.

Comment: And what have you tried? Where is your question?

Comment: As of now I'm doing this in a shell script. But i need to do this in java and integrate in GUI. So, please give idea to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the effort. I got the answer after a long try!
`

```
    String url = "http://maniv.com/maniv/rest";
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String method = "sendMessage";
    String msg_type = "binary";
    String parameter1 = "9999999";
    String parameter2 = "0000000";
    String msg = "001100110001100011";

    // ...
    StringBuffer sb = null;
    String query = String
            .format("method=%s&msg_type=%s&userid=%s&password=%s&msg=%s",
                    URLEncoder.encode(method, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(msg_type, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(userid, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(password, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(msg, charset));
    try {
        URL requestUrl = new URL(url + "?" + query);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        osw.write(query);
        osw.flush();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String in = "";
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(in + "\n");
            System.out.println("Output:\n" +in);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured" + e);
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use curl command with Java? Could you use HttpClient to get html file? http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Please refer to this question: [Read url to string in few lines of java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328711/read-url-to-string-in-few-lines-of-java-code). It provides pretty good answer.

Comment: Anything is fine.. I just need to code this. Since, i'm a newbie i just need idea for `HTTP` or `cURL` in java.

Comment: This link maybe a proper place for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html. All you need is to read html file from a URL.

Comment: Dude, mine is not a static URL. `http://maniv.com/maniv/rest?method=sendMessage&msg_type=binary&**parameter1=9999999**&**parameter2=9999999**`. The **PARAMETERT1** and **PARAMETER2** are the user inputs. So, in `URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");` i could not use.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to make a POST operation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java