# how to read data from a json file which is specified with a particular URL using java

Tags: java, json

a json file is located online, and i want to read the data from that json file using java.

example json file which is available online :[jscon file link](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=3)

thank you

Comment: [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
URL url = new URL("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=3");
URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Rate r = gson.fromJson(inputLine,Rate.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

First obtain the string directly from the URL. I believe you could use this:

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328711/read-url-to-string-in-few-lines-of-java-code)

Then from the string use the json library to build the json object. You might look into gson for more complex serialization.