# SocketTimeoutException on using execute() in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I get a `SocketTimeoutException` when I try to parse a HTML page using Jsoup:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:381)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:364)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:143)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:132)
  at app.ForumCrawler.crawl(ForumCrawler.java:50)
  at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

I have used this part of code for parsing the page, since I look for the response like 200,404 etc..

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (jsoup)";
int timeout = 5 * 1000;
Document localDoc = null;
String url = "<url>";
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(timeout).execute();
if(response.statusCode() == 200) {
    localDoc = Jsoup.parse(response.body());
    //do the stuff..
}
```

I have come across that if we use `.get()` instead of `.execute()` we can get rid of `SocketTimeoutException` issue, but if I use `.get()` then I wasn't able to get response.

please suggest me which one to use to get rid of `SocketTimeoutException` and also to get `response` when it is trying to parse the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `timeout(10*1000).get();`, does it work ? Otherwise you could use standard Java classes to download the HTML from the url as a string, and then parse with Jsoup. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328711/read-url-to-string-in-few-lines-of-java-code). What is your url ?

Comment: yep @JonasCz I have used that.. but how can I get the response if I use get(). please help me with that if you know how to get response status if I use get() method

Comment: Try `localDoc = response.parse();`, instead of `localDoc = Jsoup.parse(response.body());`. Missed that you need the response code, sorry. With `.get()` you cannot have response code. Otherwise, try the standard classes to download as a String, an then parse.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have come across that if we use .get() instead of .execute() we can get rid of SocketTimeoutException issue*

As you can see in the callstack located in your post, the `get()` method calls internally the `execute()` method:

```
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:381)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:364)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:143)<-- execute() called
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:132)<-- ...from get().
at app.ForumCrawler.crawl(ForumCrawler.java:50)
```

So you can't get rid of `SocketTimeoutException`. However, you can strenghten your code by handling this exception.