# How to get stream over lines of text at certain URL in Java 8 way?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to read those words line by line: http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt

I tried to get a Stream:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt"));
stream.forEach((word) -> System.out.println(word));
//Close the stream and it's underlying file as well
stream.close();
```

but as I suspected it works only for files. Is there similar methods for URLs?

Answer (score 16):

`BufferedReader` also has a `lines()` method returning a stream. So you just need to open a BufferedReader wrapping an InputStreamReader wrapping the URL connection input stream:

```
try (InputStream is = new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openConnection().getInputStream();
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     Stream<String> stream = reader.lines()) {
    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: You can shorten `.openConnection().getInputStream()` to `.openStream()`

Answer (score 1):

Check this question out:
[Read url to string in few lines of java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328711/read-url-to-string-in-few-lines-of-java-code)

This answer seems the most appropriate

```
Scanner(new URL("http://www.google.com").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```