# JAVA get url content after loading page

Tags: java, html, url

I use dropbox api,  and created shareable Url to an image

After loading the url in browser I got html page that contains that image, while I need only the image link.

In the html page source in browser here's the link of the image:

`<img class="preview-image absolute-center" src="<IMG-LINK>" style="visibility: visible;" data-reactid=".1.0.0">`

but when I try to get the content of the url in java servlet I find that there's no image in the content

```
URL url= new URL("<dropbox-shareable-url>");
String content = IOUtils.toString(url);
```

I think the url page first should be loaded to get the image link i need.

Is there anyway to connect and load the url before getting the content in java?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. As it stands there is too little code and explanation to clearly understand your problem

Comment: You have to call that url with something like an HTTP client to get its content and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read url to string in few lines of java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328711/read-url-to-string-in-few-lines-of-java-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this still works, but try to replace
*www.dropbox.com*
with:
*dl.dropboxusercontent.com*

Then you can fetch the direct image.
As an image:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(url)
```

Or you could use Apache Commons IO FileUtils to directly save to a File:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file)
```

Comment: replaced www.dropbox.com with dl.dropboxusercontent.com and it workes and i got the image! thank you