# Javascript: How do I run a function after a page reloads

Tags: javascript, function

My aim is to reload a page at a certain interval and run a function. 
I have read about storing the function in my localStorage and calling it when the page reloads via body onload. I wish to run this code on my console on a page so I don't think the `<body>` works. Correct me if I am wrong.

A good example would be, continued reloading of a Ebay page and it gets the prices of all toys, then it reloads and gets the price again and it continues to reload till I close the browser. But every time I reload I can't run my function.

All help is appreciated, for my understanding.

Comment: This comment does not shows how to do this in javascript but I feel approach to solve the problem can be improved. Why not write a program in your choice of language, read that url, get the content as string/xml/html, parse it, collect the values, save/use them, make the thread sleep, re-read the page. You can take help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328711/read-url-to-string-in-few-lines-of-java-code

Answer (score 0):

Small example:

```js
var 
  ready = function() {
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    
    //alert('Yay!');
    location.reload();
    
  }, 3000); // 3000 ms => 3 seconds
};
```

```html
<body onload="ready()">
  <h1>Page!</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: It's better to explain your code instead of just pasting some lines.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run some script at the **third-party website** (e.g. Ebay), reload page and do it all again.

You can use some browser extensions. For example, [that one](https://tampermonkey.net/).
This extension detect page URL and runs any script you have written for it.
So, your script automatically runs by extension, do some work, reloads page and then repeats all.

```
// script runs automatically by extension:
$( function() {
    // do some work:
    /* some work */

    // and then reloads page:
    location.reload();
} );
```

Comment: Hey exactly what i was looking for! I'll try it out

Comment: @NicholasLim glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the setinterval function.
It will repeat something afer a certain amount of time.

For the reload, its not really needed as you can call a ajax request and just change the parts that is needed.

example :

```js
 setInterval(function () { alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

It will alert out Hello every 3 secounds

Answer (score 0):

100% working. :)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10">

<script type="text/javascript">
var whenready = function() {

        alert('It Works Man..!!');
    };

</script>
</head>
    <body onLoad="whenready()">
      <h1>Page!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```