# ZERO WIDTH SPACE in Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deal with JSON and I found **/u200b** (Zero width space) right before double values. I cant pares it right now, even setting the filed type to String. Here I can easily remove it, but how to deal with downloading content from a server?

```
  String testJson = "{" +
            "    \"name\": \"Aarhus\"," +
            "    \"latitude\": \u200B56.3," +
            "    \"longitude\": \u200B10.619," 
            " }";
```

Comment: You won't be able to parse a string that doesn't have quotes around it, and numbers are not supposed to have any characters besides digits, minus etc. - so what you have here is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it is like that on a server and I have to deal with it as it is. I'm trying to download it as a String and later on remove this values.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following replacement if you already have your data in a string.

```
testJson =testJson.replaceAll("\u200B", "");
```

If you need to load data from url first, then some clever ways are discussed here: [Read url to string in few lines of java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328711/read-url-to-string-in-few-lines-of-java-code)

Comment: with code above yes.. but now when instead of String you have URL

Comment: Can't you convert it to a huge string and remove the zero-width spaces before parsing it as JSON?

Comment: @Serafins I just added link to hints about loading data from URL

Comment: apparently it doesn't work. As soon as I figured it out. I will accept your answer

Comment: @Serafins give more info: what have you tried, what result etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Jackson, it has many options such as FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES and ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY. It might help