# Get the inputstream from a given downloadable link in java

Tags: java, http, url, https, download

I have to convert a file into a string where the file should be obtained from the given downloadable url link

```
String result = "";
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(downloadablelink);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {}
```

I have tried this but I get the html content of the page as the result.
what should I do?

Comment: Is this URL a direct download link to your file or to the HTML page containing the download link? If you do this in the browser do you have to login before you can download the file?

Comment: Did you read the resulting HTML? Maybe this is some kind of error message.

Comment: The url is a direct download link to the file
The html was not a error message

Comment: url.openstream does url.openConnection().getInputStream()

Comment: Hey check this is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328733/7020538