# Get all values from JSON with same tag to list

Tags: java, json

JSON is on this link: https://blockchain.info/block-height/613974?format=json

How can I get all strings tagged with "addr".

I know how can I get one but I need to modify it somehow to get all into list:

```
try {
            String sURL = "https://blockchain.info/block-height/613974?format=json";
            URL url = new URL(sURL);
            URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
            request.connect();
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
            JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
            JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); 
            String addr= rootobj.get("addr").getAsString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse through entire json using JSONArray or JSONObject depending on the element type. You can try with following code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        List<String> addrList = new ArrayList<>();
        // json is the String representing the input json
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray blocks = jsonObj.getJSONArray("blocks");
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject block = blocks.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray tx = block.getJSONArray("tx");
            for (int j = 0; j < tx.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject txItem = tx.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray out = txItem.getJSONArray("out");
                for (int k = 0; k < out.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject outItem = out.getJSONObject(k);
                    if (outItem.has("addr")) {
                        addrList.add(outItem.getString("addr"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        addrList.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
    }
```

Library used:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
```

You might have to add some more `if` conditions to check if a key exists, similar to `if (outItem.has("addr")) {`

Comment: Thank You on answer, what library should I use for JSON and how can I get "json" variable?

Comment: `json` variable is the String representing the json which you are fetching using `URLConnection`. I have updated the answer with library used.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this, so I should use: String json = "https://blockchain.info/block-height/613974?format=json";

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328733/1776132 to see how to read a String using URLConnection

Comment: Thank You! I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use JsonPath to parse json content and it saves a lot of work.

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

List<Object> allAddr = JsonPath.read(jsonData,"$.blocks[*].tx[*].out[*].addr");
    System.out.println(allAddr);
```

Even you can use rest-assured instead of url/https library.

```
public static void main(String...a) {
    //

    String jsonData  = given().contentType("application/json").expect().log().all().statusCode(200)
                    .when().
                    get("https://blockchain.info/block-height/613974?format=json")
                    .then().extract().body().asString();
    List<Object> allAddr = JsonPath.read(jsonData,"$.blocks[*].tx[*].out[*].addr");
    System.out.println(allAddr);
}
```

dependency used :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am getting error at "given()." - cannot find symbol

Comment: add dependency of com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path and com.jayway.restassured.rest-assured in project. Also import :- import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;

Comment: Well now I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured