# How get html when you use HttpsURLConnection and it return code 302

Tags: android, http, forms, post, authentication

I want to connect at login form. I send informations for connections. The problem, after identification, the website do a redirection and when i test my Object HttpsURLConnection with method connection.getResponseCode(), i have code 302 (HTTP Status-Code 302: Temporary Redirect.)

1. how can use my object connection for get html code after redirection?
2. How can use my connetion for navigate in all site after connection?

   ```
       HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       connection.setDoOutput(true);
       connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

       request.write("login=ll&password=pp");
       request.flush();
       request.close();            
       String line = "";               
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
       //.... get string
   ```

thx for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the location header to see where you've been redirected to

```
String header = connection.getHeaderField("location");
```

and then open a new connection to that URL.

You are most likely being redirected from HTTPS (login) to HTTP (post login). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/java-doesnt-follow-redirect-in-urlconnection/1884427#1884427) to another question for information on why HttpURLConnection is not automatically following the redirect in this case.

Comment: thx for get next url but when i open a new connection at this adress, he don't have logged.
When i send a bad password, i have error message. If i have put good password, i have redirection. how HttpsURLConnection get sessions? i need get another informations?