# HttpUrlConnection to get title of the content and got "Moved Permanently"

Tags: java, http, groovy, htmlcleaner

This is my code I've written in Groovy to get the page title out of a URL. However, some website I got "Moved Permanently" which I think this is because of the 301 Redirect. How do I avoid this and let the HttpUrlConnection to follow to the right URL and get the correct page title

For example this website I got "Moved Permanently" instead of the correct page title 
http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/14/arts/music/jay-z-and-kanye-wests-watch-the-throne.html

```
        def con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection()
        con.connect()

        def inputStream = con.inputStream

        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner()
        CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties()

        TagNode node = cleaner.clean(inputStream)
        TagNode titleNode = node.findElementByName("title", true);

        def title = titleNode.getText().toString()
        title = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(title).trim()
        title = title.replace("\n", "");
        return title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get this to work if I manage the redirecting myself...

I think the issue is that the site will expect cookies that it sends half way down the redirect chain, and if it doesn't get them, it sends you to a log-in page.

This code obviously needs some cleaning up (and there is probably a better way to do this), but it shows how I can extract the title:

```
@Grab( 'net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.2' )
@Grab( 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' )
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
import org.htmlcleaner.*

String location = 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/14/arts/music/jay-z-and-kanye-wests-watch-the-throne.html'
String cookie = null
String pageContent = ''

while( location ) {
  new URL( location ).openConnection().with { con ->
    // We'll do redirects ourselves
    con.instanceFollowRedirects = false

    // If we got a cookie last time round, then add it to our request
    if( cookie ) con.setRequestProperty( 'Cookie', cookie )
    con.connect()

    // Get the response code, and the location to jump to (in case of a redirect)
    int responseCode = con.responseCode
    location = con.getHeaderField( "Location" )

    // Try and get a cookie the site will set, we will pass this next time round
    cookie = con.getHeaderField( "Set-Cookie" )

    // Read the HTML and close the inputstream
    pageContent = con.inputStream.withReader { it.text }
  }
}

// Then, clean paceContent and get the title
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner()
CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties()

TagNode node = cleaner.clean( pageContent )
TagNode titleNode = node.findElementByName("title", true);

def title = titleNode.text.toString()
title = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml( title ).trim()
title = title.replace( "\n", "" )

println title
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setInstanceFollowRedirects(true) on the HttpUrlConnection.  i.e. after the first line, insert
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)

Comment: I tried that, but it still didn't work. and I think setInstainceFollowRedirects(true) is default. But thanks a lot for you r reply.

Comment: Yeah I should have tried myself before posting.  I did reproduce your symptom but don't see why yet.  I tried HttpBuilder instead of HttpUrlConnection, and it follows the redirect with no additonal configuration.  But I haven't been able to get the resulting content passed through to HtmlCleaner yet.

Comment: It's not the nyt paywall affecting things is it?

Comment: It might be because of that. But any more thoughts about that?

Comment: I copied that URL on facebook and facebook can recognise that, may be I'm missing something else?

Comment: Just been reading another answer, Java engineers decided to disable the follow redirect, so it has to be manually done by application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/java-doesnt-follow-redirect-in-urlconnection

Comment: The disabling of the flow redirect only applied to redirects to a different protocol.  In the case of your NYT URL, the redirect is to the same protocol (from http: to http:), so that response does not apply.