# How to download text file from Github?

Tags: xml, url, github, download

What link to use to get automatic file download for text file from GitHub?

This example works for binary files, but not for text based, like xml

```
http://github.com/downloads/TheHolyWaffle/ChampionHelper/ChampionHelper-4.jar
```

File is at

```
https://raw.github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/master/ENodeIDE.p2f
```

Related to [Download binary file from Github using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441720)

Comment: Just look at GitHub and get a link to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not Github, the problem is your browser: if the file can be directly readed the it will, but if he cannot (like for binary file for example), then it will be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox

<kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Save Page As</kbd>

Internet Explorer

<kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Save as</kbd>