# HttpURLConnection follow redirects not redirecting jsp

Tags: jsp, rest, http, redirect, httpurlconnection

I am having trouble trying to get HttpURLConnection to follow redirects. What I am trying to accomplish is getting the xml file from a rest api. Here's the code I wrote for the connection.

```
  URL url = new URL("***some url*****");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setFollowRedirects(true);
  conn.addRequestProperty("X-IntegrationServer-Username", "");
  conn.addRequestProperty("X-IntegrationServer-Password", "");
  conn.setRequestProperty("ContentType", "application/xml");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "");
  conn.connect();
  out.print("<br>Response code = " + conn.getResponseCode());
  out.print("<br>Response message = " + conn.getResponseMessage() + "<br><br>");
```

On my page I am getting a 302 response code still

```
Response code = 302
Response message = Found
```

Where can I look to see why this redirect isn't happening. I thought setting .setfollowredirects took any 3xx response and continued. Am I missing something?

If it means anything I did get this URL connection to work with php and a webdebugger fiddler and was able to get the data.

**UPDATE**

I think the issue might actually revolve around going from http and being redirected to a https link. I saw that in another topic but didn't see that mine was similiar to now.

[URLConnection Doesn't Follow Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/java-doesnt-follow-redirect-in-urlconnection)