# Spring RestTemplate redirect 302

Tags: spring, rest, redirect, response, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to use spring rest template to do a post request to login in.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
mvm.add("LoginForm_Login", "login");
mvm.add("LoginForm_Password", "password");

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uriDWLogin, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

My ResponseEntity status is 302, i want to follow this request to get the body response , because i didn't get the body for this request.

```
18:59:59.170 MAIN [http-nio-8080-exec-83] DEBUG c.d.s.c.DemandwareCtlr - loginToSandbox - StatusResponse - 302
18:59:59.170 MAIN [http-nio-8080-exec-83] DEBUG c.d.s.c.DemandwareCtlr - loginToSandbox - BodyResponse -
```

What can I do to solve this problem ?!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The redirection is followed automatically if the request is a GET request (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418583/follow-302-redirect-using-spring-resttemplate)). To make it happen on POST requests, one option might be to use a different request factory, like `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, and set it to use an `HttpClient` with the required settings to follow the redirect (see [LaxRedirectStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/LaxRedirectStrategy.html)):

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                               .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                                               .build();
factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

I haven't tested, but this should work.

Comment: Tks for your help, it works, now i need to get the "Cookie" not the "Set-cookie", how i could do it ?

Comment: just get the "Set-Cookie" from the headers, just like you would with cookie, result.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie").get(0).split(";")[0];

Comment: If org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient is on the classpath, the behaviour of RestTemplate is different - it does not follow redirects on GETs (with the default constructor).

Comment: `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` doesn't follow redirectS it follows redirecT. Only one.