# Set status code 301 or 303 in Spring RestTemplate and ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, http-status-code-301

I've created a GET service to redirect to a webpage that uses POST. 
I'm trying to use `restTemplate` because with this I can send the body and header that request the service and I've achieved to get the information that a I need from the service.

However, I need to redirect to the server that has the POST service, but I couldn't, because I don't know how can a set the status code which I redirect to another server.

These are the functions that I'm using:

```java
RequestEntity<Object> req = new RequestEntity<Object>(body, httpHeaders, HttpMethod.POST, url);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, req, String.class);
```

Comment: Could you share the code of your GET and POST? I didn't understanf what for you are using restTemplate for this case. Redirecting can be performed simply with using the `HttpServletResponse ` in your contoller method. Check this answer, maybe it will help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418583/follow-302-redirect-using-spring-resttemplate

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this as http post are not redirected automatically in spring. So the following might help:

```java
 public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
 final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String url = "http://localhost:8080/my-sample-post-url";
 final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory =
     new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

 final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
     .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();       
     //org.apache.httpcomponents 
 factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
 restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);

 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,params,String.class);
 if(response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
   return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
 }
 else {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND); // for example only
 }
 
 }
```

> Note: Lax RedirectStrategy implementation that automatically redirects all HEAD, GET, POST, and DELETE requests. This strategy relaxes restrictions on automatic redirection of POST methods imposed by the HTTP specification.  [More here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/LaxRedirectStrategy.html)