# JAXRS 2.0 Client: FOLLOW_REDIRECTS property doesn't work

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-client

I'm trying to get autoredirects to work in Jersey Client 2.0. Here is my code:

```
ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig().property(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);
Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
WebTarget wt = c.target("some_path");
SystemInfo info = wt.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(SystemInfo.class);
```

Server sends HTTP 302 with an another URL in Location header as expected. I assume that according to the [Jersey JAXRS Client API](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/2.0/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.html#FOLLOW_REDIRECTS) the client will redirect automatically to the new specified URL, but I'm getting a [RedirectionException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/RedirectionException.html) instead.

Is it the appropriate behaviour? How to bring client redirection to work without implementing redirection mannually in try-catch-block?

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATED:**

I've found the problem point of strange behaviour. If redirection made on server programmatically with something like:

```
return Response.seeOther(another_uri).build();
```

everything is fine. But in my case, redirection made due to security-constraint element in deployment descriptor:

```
<security-constraint>
    ...
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Thus, the client is redirected from `http:// localhost:8080/some_path` to `https:// localhost:8181/another_path` automatically by servlet container.
In browser it works fine, but Jersey client seems to be ignoring FOLLOW_REDIRECTS property and throws an RedirectionException instead.

Is there a chance in this case to get redirection working properly? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with FOLLOW_REDIRECTS with true?

Comment: yep you should have : ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig().property(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);

Comment: Thanks, corrected! I played with all possible configuration variants and "false" value was mistakenly copy-pasted. In fact, setting FOLLOW_REDIRECTS property to the value "true" gives no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigations I found that `Jersey Client` is not responsible for the problem. Its a general Java `HttpURLConnection` behaviour (or better to say security limitaion) if `Location` header of the response has some another scheme, than originated URL.

So, if request redirects in some manner (response code 3xx) to a resource with other scheme, `HttpURLConnection` will ignore `followRedirects` flag and return with appropriate response code. Otherwise, if `followRedirects=true`, it sends subsequent request to the proposed URL and returns response from that resource.

See [Java doesn't follow redirect in URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/java-doesnt-follow-redirect-in-urlconnection) for more information.