# Making GET call from Android returns 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: android, http

I have an Android app which makes an http GET call. The code is pretty simple:

```
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    buff.append(str);
}
// do stuff with the data
```

Recently the call has stopped working, and I get a 301 Moved Permanently response. However the call works perfectly well from a browser.

What would cause this? Is it a deliberate attempt to reject my request? Is there anything I can change to get around this?

Comment: you may want to add `urlc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);` (and cast urlc to HttpURLConnection) or just `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);`

Comment: it could also be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/java-doesnt-follow-redirect-in-urlconnection (https in redirect form an http url)

Comment: Thank you so much, one of the answers on the question you linked to has helped me out. (The answer by Nathan on Sept 25th 2014). Thanks again!