# How to make Apache HttpClient (via Jersey) less verbose?

Tags: java, jersey, slf4j, logback, apache-httpclient-4.x

Take http://smile.amazon.com/` for example. It has

1. Redirect from `http` to `https`
2. Invalid domain cookies

I'm using Jersey as a HTTP client, but because of #1 I'm using it with `ApacheConnectorProvider` as default [`HttpURLConnection` doesn't follow http-to-https redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/urlconnection-doesnt-follow-redirect#comment1784909_1884427).

I want to capture the #2 warnings to SLF4J with `logback` so I'm using `jul-to-slf4j` bridge.

[image]

```
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

[image]

It seems to work exactly as I want it to, but [documentation strongly suggests using `LevelChangePropagator`](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) for performance reasons.

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
```

However, it is now logging way too much.

[image]

How can I configure Jersey and/or Apache HttpClient internals to be much less verbose?

Comment: Your logback-level is set to debug, with the `LevelChangePropagator`, the jul-level is also on Debug, thats why you'll get all the message. See the possible dublicate on how to change the level for the package `org.apache.http` to warn

Comment: @hinneLinks there seem to be a ton of packages involved, I'd like to configure it in client, rather than filter in logback, if possible.

Comment: Then you'll either need to adjust the jul-configuration or remove the `LevelChangePropagator`. The Performance impact will happen, if jul creates a lot of debug-messages, that are filtered by logback in the end. if jul doesn't create them in the first place you should be fine (you don't see the debug-messages in the second screenshot, so i assume the jul-level is on info by default)

Comment: @hinneLinks thanks