# When using URL.openConnection(), what is the best way to handle URL variations like "www" and "https"?

Tags: java, url, web-crawler, urlconnection

When opening a connection, how can I find out the best URL format to use?

Many sites return different results based on whether the URL uses "www" and/or "https".

For example, here's a test that I wrote to see some of the different results:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String baseURL = "google.com";

      try
      {
         java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://" + baseURL);
         java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
         connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

         String line;
         int lineCount = 0;

         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
            lineCount++;
         }

         System.out.println("http://" + baseURL + " = " + lineCount + " lines");
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println("http://" + baseURL + " throws an error");
      }



      try
      {
         java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://www." + baseURL);
         java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
         connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

         String line;
         int lineCount = 0;

         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
          lineCount++;
         }

         System.out.println("http://www." + baseURL + " = " + lineCount + " lines");
      }

      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println("http://www." + baseURL + " throws an error");
      }







      try
      {
         java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("https://" + baseURL);
         java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
         connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

         String line;
         int lineCount = 0;

         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
            lineCount++;
         }

         System.out.println("https://" + baseURL + " = " + lineCount + " lines");
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println("https://" + baseURL + " throws an error");
      }



      try
      {
         java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("https://www." + baseURL);
         java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
         connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

         String line;
         int lineCount = 0;

         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
            lineCount++;
         }

         System.out.println("https://www." + baseURL + " = " + lineCount + " lines");
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println("https://www." + baseURL + " throws an error");
      }
   }
}
```

Here were the results of running it on four different websites:

```
http://stackoverflow.com = 4205 lines
http://www.stackoverflow.com = 4205 lines
https://stackoverflow.com = 4205 lines
https://www.stackoverflow.com = 2 lines
```

```
http://qvc.com = 2438 lines
http://www.qvc.com = 2438 lines
https://qvc.com throws an error
https://www.qvc.com = 0 lines
```

```
http://facebook.com = 0 lines
http://www.facebook.com = 0 lines
https://facebook.com = 25 lines
https://www.facebook.com = 25 lines
```

```
http://google.com = 6 lines
http://www.google.com = 6 lines
https://google.com = 343 lines
https://www.google.com = 343 lines
```

Given a base URL, like "google.com", what's the proper way of checking to see which format I should use for the website?

Comment: Presumably, the reply on http is a redirect to the secure https protocol.

Comment: check the response code. if you get a redirect, then you probably used the wrong format. e.g. `www.stackoverflow.com` will issue a 301 redirect to just `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @MarcB - Yeah, I figured it would be something like that. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: This looks useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/urlconnection-doesnt-follow-redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Marc B's answer, a few other StackOverflow threads (which I linked in the original question's comments), and [this guide](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/), here's what I came up with:

```
String baseURL = "google.com";

try
{
     java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://" + baseURL);
     java.net.HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
     connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");

     int response = connection.getResponseCode();
     System.out.println("Response code: " + response);

     if (response == 301 || response == 302 || response == 303)
     {
            System.out.println("Redirect location: " + connection.getHeaderField("Location"));
     }

     else
     {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            int lineCount = 0;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
            lineCount++;
            }

            System.out.println("http://" + baseURL + " = " + lineCount + " lines\n");
     }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
     System.out.println("http://" + baseURL + " throws an error\n");
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
Response code: 302
Redirect location: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
```

You can also use `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP`, `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM`, and `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER` instead of the numeric response codes. That's probably a better practice, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Check the HTTP response code. If you get a redirect, then you probably used the wrong format. e.g. `http://www.stackoverflow.com` will do a 301 redirect to just `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Isn't there a way to tell the request to follow redirects?

Comment: Probably, but I don't do java, so no idea what option it'd be.

Comment: `Isn't there a way to tell the request to follow redirects?` Cast the URLConnection to an [HttpURLConnect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and call `setFollowRedirects(true);`

Comment: @copeg- According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)), it's set to follow redirects by default, but it doesn't do what you would expect it to. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26046079/1741346) for more details.