# JAVA picture download protection - can't download

Tags: java, image, download

I want to download picture from URL - direct link to a picture.
It is somehow protected, when I try  :

```
InputStream in = new URL("http://www.somesite.sk/somepicture.jpg") 
Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:/picture.jpg"));
```

it downloads, but not as the original picture, the file "picture.jpg" has only this text inside :

```
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://www.somesite.sk/somepicture.jpg">here</a></body>
```

when I try direct download - right mouse-click and Save Picture, it works, if I try some download manager, it works.
Some idea?

Comment: I wouldn't mind an actual link to the image to try some things out in order to answer your question. Would it be possible to have one?
My first guess is a User Agent problem.

Comment: use another httpClient and make sure you Enable the redirect following. See here to get samples - http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-stop-follow-redirect

Comment: MadWard : http://www.temponabytok.sk/Files/obrazky/10010483.jpg

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/urlconnection-doesnt-follow-redirect . The Location header contains the same URL with an `https` scheme.  Using the https URL directly is one possible workaround.

Comment: VGR : great, it was exactly the problem, didn't realized, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it. Put these dependencies into your pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import java.io.File;

public class ImageDownloader {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        HttpClient instance = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://yourhost.blah/yuorfile.jpg");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = instance.execute(httpGet);
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getEntity().getContent(), new File("output.jpg"));    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }   
}
```

---

hope it helps

Comment: If you could help me little bit more : where do I find the pom.xml file?

Comment: You can download the jars directly from the Apache project page. Just Google them.