# Downloading binary file from url

Tags: java, file, url, download

I am using this code to download files from a url:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File("C:/Songs/newsong.mp3"));
```

When I create the url using for instance, 
    "https://mjcdn.cc/2/282676442/MjUgU2FhbCAtIFZlZXQgQmFsaml0Lm1wMw==",
this works just fine and the mp3 is downloaded.
However,
if I use another url: 
    "https://dl.jatt.link/hd.jatt.link/a0339e7c772ed44a770a3fe29e3921a8/uttzv/Hummer-(Mr-Jatt.com).mp3",
the file is 0kb.

I am able to download files from both these urls from within a web browser.
What's wrong here, and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed a difference between your 2 URLs:

- The first one just gives back the file [without redirection](http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?page=single&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmjcdn.cc%2F2%2F282676442%2FMjUgU2FhbCAtIFZlZXQgQmFsaml0Lm1wMw%3D%3D&useragent=1&typeProtocol=11).
- But the second one [responds with a redirect](http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?page=single&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.jatt.link%2Fhd.jatt.link%2Fa0339e7c772ed44a770a3fe29e3921a8%2Futtzv%2FHummer-%28Mr-Jatt.com%29.mp3&useragent=1&typeProtocol=11) (`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`). It's also a special case, because it's a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP protocol.

Browsers can follow redirects, but your program - for some reason (see below) - can't.

I suggest you to use a HTTP client library (e.g. [Apache HTTP client](https://hc.apache.org/) or [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)), and configure it to follow redirects (if they don't do it by default).

For example, with Jsoup, you would need a code like this:

```
String url = "https://dl.jatt.link/hd.jatt.link/a0339e7c772ed44a770a3fe29e3921a8/uttzv/Hummer-(Mr-Jatt.com).mp3";
String filename = "C:/Songs/newsong.mp3";
Response r = Jsoup.connect(url)
    //.followRedirects(true) // follow redirects (it's the default)
    .ignoreContentType(true) // accept not just HTML
    .maxBodySize(10*1000*1000) // accept 10M bytes (default is 1M), or set to 0 for unlimited
    .execute(); // send GET request
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
out.write(r.bodyAsBytes());
out.close();
```

---

**Update on @EJP's comment:**

- I looked up Apache Commons IO's [`FileUtils` class on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java). It calls `openStream()` of the received `URL` object.
- [`openStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) is a shorthand for `openConnection().inputStream()`.
- [`openConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) returns an `URLConnection` object. If there is an appropriate subclass for the protocol used by `URL`, it will return an instance of that subclass. In this case that's a [`HttpsURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) which is the subclass of `HttpURLConnection`.
- The [followRedirects option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)) is defined in `HttpURLConnection` and it's indeed `true` by default:

> Sets whether HTTP redirects (requests with response code 3xx) should be automatically followed by this class. **True by default.**

- So **OP's approach would normally work with redirects too, but it seems that redirection from HTTPS to HTTP is not handled (properly) by `HttpsURLConnection`.** - It's the case that @VGR mentioned in the comments below.
- It's possible to handle redirects manually by reading the `Location` header with `HttpsURLConnection`, then use it in a new `HttpURLConnection`. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/urlconnection-doesnt-follow-redirect)) (I wouldn't be surprised if Jsoup did the same.)
- I suggested Jsoup because it already implements a way to handle HTTPS to HTTP redirections correctly and also provides tons of useful features.

Comment: Note that a redirect from an `https` URL to an `http` URL is considered insecure, so many libraries will not follow it even when requested to follow redirects.

Comment: You are surely right and thank you. :) Though I've just tried out Jsoup with the URL above, and works perfectly. :)

Comment: Thanks... I just figured that it was because I wasn't following the redirect. Thanks for letting me know of a simple way to follow the redirect and consume the response as bytes using Jsoup. Coincidentally, I'm already using Jsoup for a part of my application!

Comment: Wouldn't `FileUtils` already use this class? and doesn't it already follow redirects by default? If not, why not? and if not, why not just use `HttpURLConnection', which does follow redirects by default?

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the questions/notes! I made some research upon those, please see my updated answer. I hope I could improve it. :)