# Fatal Error :1:1: Premature end of file - in Url.openStream() / new new XmlReader in Rome tools

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, rome

Small snippet of program challenging me from a day,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.rometools.rome.io.FeedException;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, FeedException, IOException {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream openStream = new URL("http://www.livemint.com/rss/money").openStream();
        Document doc = db.parse(openStream);
        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentURI());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

All this experiment started from the rome tools parser code, which was giving me same error in different approaches also.

```
SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(url));
feed.getEntries();
```

Exception was getting thrown in creating new xml Reader, so i wrote a test program in different approach. Now both are throwing the same error,

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.

I have to fetch xml response from a url, but not able to do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because the server is trying to redirect you to use `https` instead of `http`, while `HttpURLConnection` [does not support that automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26046079/597657).

Changing your URL to use `https` would solve the issue.

Comment: might be not sure, but this code was working ,SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(url));
feed.getEntries();
Suddenly started breaking like this.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a GET request to this URL from Java Code says:

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : http://www.livemint.com/rss/money
Response Code : 301
```

So the XML is not present in the response as the request fails. Please check the API and see if you have to include any extra parameters in the HTTP request.

I used following code to connect to the URL:

```
  public static String getUrlResponse(String url) throws IOException {
             URL obj = new URL(url);
             HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
             // optional default is GET
             con.setRequestMethod("GET");
             //add request header
             int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
             System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
             System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
             String inputLine;
             StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
             }
             in.close();
             //print in String
             return response.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried with also already nothing will be in.readLine(), whole while loop will be skipped.

Comment: xml is present in the URL, if you put the url into browser we will get rss feeds.

Comment: how can i handle that ?