# File not downloaded from some HTTP URLs

Tags: java, io, bufferedinputstream

I am using url to download a this jar but it downloads 0kb file. I using other url even ftp url is working just fine, the issue is only with this file.

url which is not working

> http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar

Using below code.

```
try 
{
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    String fileName = DownloadSourceUtils.getUniqueFileName(DownloadSourceConstants.DOWNLOAD_LOCALTION, url.getFile());

    File directory = new File(DownloadSourceConstants.DOWNLOAD_LOCALTION);
    if (! directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdir();
        // If you require it to make the entire directory path including parents,
        // use directory.mkdirs(); here instead.
    }

    fos = new FileOutputStream(DownloadSourceConstants.DOWNLOAD_LOCALTION+File.separator+fileName);

    byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = bis.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) 
    {
        fos.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fos.flush();
    output = url + " downloaded successfully";
    return output;
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    output = e.getMessage();
    return output;
}
finally
{
    if(bis != null)
        bis.close();
    if(fos != null)
        fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that URL redirects to another, which is HTTPS:

```
$ curl -i http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2018 14:37:09 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.45
Connection: keep-alive
```

So I'd update your URL to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
See [URLConnection Doesn't Follow Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/urlconnection-doesnt-follow-redirect) for good discussions around the Java reasons for this not working.

Comment: Thanks it worked. but just thinking shouldnt it give this message moved permanently rather than silently not downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

The request is redirected to `HTTPS`. And therefore no content is given.

If you change the link to `HTTPS`, everything works.